# Trouble with AJAX and data format

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some code that uses jQuery's `$.ajax()`.

I found that I had to pass my data through `JSON.stringify()`.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Resource/ReportError',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        ResourceId: popup.data('id'),
        Reason: reason,
        Description: $('#report-error-description').val(),
        Email: $('#report-error-email').val()
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function () {
        // ...
    }
});
```

So far, so good. But now I'm using it to get some data, passing in only an ID. So I figured I should be using **GET** instead.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Resource/GetInitialReviewData',
    type: 'GET',
    data: JSON.stringify({ resourceId: resourceId }),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // ...
    },
    error: function () {
        // ...
    }
});
```

But this fails with an error about the `resourceId` being `null` on the server.

If I remove the call to `JSON.stringify()`, then it works!

```
data: { resourceId: resourceId },
```

Can anyone explain this in a way that's easy to understand? Why do I need `JSON.stringify` for **POST** but not for **GET**.

Comment: You do not need `JSON.stringify()` for a POST if the properties of you model are simple types (but you need to remove `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',`. Also adding `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` in a GET is pointless (it has no body)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: So it's the `contentType` that is messing me up here? Would love to see you flesh this comment out a little more into an answer.

Comment: I need to think about how to do that without writing a small book chapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use `JSON.stringify()` for a POST, although you can (but it is generally unnecessary unless your manually generating complex types or arrays which do not match the c# dot and indexer notation). The default `contentType` for the `$.ajax()` method is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` which is essentially like a giant query string of the successful forms controls name/value pairs. To see what it would look like, your can use `console.log($('form').serialize());`.

If you omit the `contentType` then you can use the object without stringifying it.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Resource/ReportError',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        ResourceId: popup.data('id'),
        Reason: reason,
        Description: $('#report-error-description').val(),
        Email: $('#report-error-email').val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
```

The `DefaultModelBinder` will then use the `FormValueProvider` to read and bind the data to your method parameters.

When you use `JSON.stringify()` it converts your object to JSON-formatted text - a giant string containing the name/value pairs (notice the quotes around the resulting value) and you could receive this by having a single `string` parameter in your method and deserializing it yourself. By adding the `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'` the `DefaultModelBinder` will now use the `JsonValueProviderFactory` to read the string, deserialize it (using the `JavaScriptSerializer`) and bind the data to your method parameters.

In the case of a GET, there is no body, and the `contentType` option is not applicable (it will be ignored) as the `DefaultModelBinder` will only read the values from the query string (or route values). As noted in maddockst's answer, by using `JSON.stringify()` in your `$.ajax()` GET call, your generating a url of

```
.../Resource/GetInitialReviewData{"resourceId":"someValue"}
```

instead of the required

```
.../Resource/GetInitialReviewData?resourceId=someValue
```

Answer (score 3):

The `data` attribute when used in conjunction with `type: 'GET'` will convert the value specified into a query string and append it to the URL. So if you called the URL `http://www.test.com` with data `{name: 'Tom'}`, you'd end up with the following URL:

```
http://www.test.com?name=Tom
```

If you pass a string, that string will be appended to the URL so the resulting URL when calling `JSON.stringify` would be:

```
http://www.test.com{"name":"tom"}
```

When you use `data` with `type: 'POST'`, `data` is sent in the body of the request. The body of the request needs to be a string, the reason for the call to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: The last paragraph is not correct. The default `contentType` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'` (a collection of name/value pairs)